# Checkbox capturing value but not showing checked after submission

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, forms-services

I have an InfoPath form in Sharepoint that uses checkbox values to calculate a total value. When the form is completed and submitted, the values from the boxes that are checked are being recorded successfully, but when the user goes into the form to view it, these boxes are showing to be unchecked. I cannot find a reason why.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use "1" for checked and "0" for cleared?

If that’s the case, I recommend you use "TRUE" for checked, and "FALSE" for cleared, then check again.

Here is a similar post for your reference: [InfoPath 2010 Checkbox does not display value in display mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f8537c0-eb0f-431f-ac68-f76a8128f4ae/infopath-2010-checkbox-does-not-display-value-in-display-mode?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)